# XML not filtering out results from file in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

This is the sample XML that I have got:

```
<ArrayOfService >
  <Service z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
          <primaryUrl>http://www.buses.co.uk/1A</primaryUrl>
          <relativePosition>2</relativePosition>
          <serviceDescription>Whitehawk - County Hospital - City Centre - Hove - Portslade - Mile Oak</serviceDescription>
          <serviceId>1150</serviceId>
          <serviceName>1A</serviceName>
          <serviceNotes />
          <serviceText>Whitehawk - Mile Oak</serviceText>
          <serviceUrls />
     </Service>
</ArrayOfService>
```

This is the code:

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("services.xml");
//XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusExpress.ClassLibrary";

var list = (from item in loadedData.Descendants("ArrayOfService").Descendants("Service")
            where (string)item.Element("serviceName") == "1A"
            select (string)item.Element("serviceId")).FirstOrDefault();
```

The result is coming out as null, why is this?

Comment: At which line is it coming null?

Comment: Good question - I can't somehow debug in the code, only the list is Null when it completes. So I assume that the where is not working as when I remove that, it completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the problem, but I just copied the contents of the xml into another file and this then worked.

Answer (score 1):

`loadedData.Descendants("ArrayOfService")` should be `loadedData.Root`

See [XDocument.Root (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.root%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: I get the following error if I try that: Non-invocable member 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Root' cannot be used like a method

Comment: It's a property, not a method. So skip the parenthesis, and read up on the basics of C#.